# django rest framework nested filter

Tags: python, django, filter, nested, django-rest-framework

I want to get all the "Registro_Entrada" and filter them by "Entrante" when "fk_tipo_entrante" is equal to "2".

On VIEWS.py I have:

```
class GetPersonalEntranteRegistro_EntradaAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = Registro_EntradaNestedSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        entrante = Entrante.objects.all().filter(fk_tipo_entrante=2)
        registro = Registro_Entrada.objects.filter(fk_entrante = entrante.pk)
        return registro
```

On SERIALIZERS.py I have:

```
class Registro_EntradaNestedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fk_tarifa = TarifaSerializer(many=False)
    fk_entrante = EntranteNestedSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Registro_Entrada
        fields = ('_all_')
```

On MODELS.py I have:

```
class Entrante(models.Model):
    fk_credencial = models.ForeignKey(Credencial,related_name='credencial_entrada',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_placa = models.ForeignKey(Placa, related_name='credencial_placa',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_tipo_entrante = models.ForeignKey(Tipo_Entrante,related_name='entrante_tipo',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona,related_name='entrante_persona',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estatus = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Registro_Entrada(models.Model):
    fecha_entrada = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    fecha_salida = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    fk_tarifa = models.ForeignKey(Tarifa,related_name='registro_tarifa',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fk_entrante = models.ForeignKey(Entrante,related_name='regitro_entrante',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    costo = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=50)
    saldo = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=50)
    estatus = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

It shows the following error:

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'

Comment: `entrante = Entrante.objects.all().filter(fk_tipo_entrante=2).first()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to filter by many `pk` form first query you can try use `__in` without `pk`:

```
entrante = Entrante.objects.filter(fk_tipo_entrante=2)
registro = Registro_Entrada.objects.filter(fk_entrante__in=entrante)
#                                                    ^^^^        ^^^
```

read more details [django in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have problem here:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    entrante = Entrante.objects.all().filter(fk_tipo_entrante=2)
    registro = Registro_Entrada.objects.filter(fk_entrante = entrante.pk) # this line
```

`entrante` is a queryset. So it does not have `pk` attribute. So you can try like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
     entrante = Entrante.objects.all().filter(fk_tipo_entrante=2)
     if entrante.exists():
         _entrante = entrante.first() # Or you can use `.get()` method of django queryset
         registro = Registro_Entrada.objects.filter(fk_entrante = _entrante.pk)
     else:
        registro = Registro_Entrada.objects.none() # Or .all() , or any logic you want
```

Comment: It stop showing the error but did not bring the objects, the thing that worked for me was the answer of Bear Brown.